# Error when running apt-get update for nordvpn

Tags: apt, repository

So I have been trying to install nordvpn recently, I have been faced with an error in the process.

I installed the .deb file by:

```
sudo apt-get install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

then I ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

To then get this output:

```
Ign:17 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                       
Err:18 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable Release
  Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 104.17.50.74 443]
Reading package lists... Done                    
E: The repository 'https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So now can I by anyway get past this? (please help)

Comment: did it work when you installed it with `sudo apt-get install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb` ? precise command would be `sudo apt-get install {/path/to/}nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb`

Comment: Also maybe worth mentioning that unless you need some feature of the client you can download and import nordvpn .ovpn files through network settings and do away with the client completely. I had issues with their client so now do it through settings and Ubuntu top-right dropdown menu and not had any problems since.

Comment: @JoKeR yes it actually worked

Comment: @codlord how so? I only need nordvpn to connect to .ovpn files so I can join tryhackme

Comment: The easiest way to configure NordVPN on any Ubuntu is to follow the steps they provided in FAQ for manual setup https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/

Comment: the issue for me was that nordvpn domain is blocked here in Dubai. Had to turn on nordvpn in order to get updates from nordvpn.

Answer (score 3):

Bit late to the party but the solution that worked for me is not directly mentioned in the answers of the post. Leaving it here in case it can help anyone.

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main" > nordvpn.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nordvpn
```

Basically add the repo to the list of sources but with `[trusted=true]` which is the part that other answers don't mention and that goes around the restriction:

```
E: The repository 'https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question but OP asked how to use NordVPN (or other VPN) without a client so for NordVPN I did this:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/archives/servers/ovpn.zip
unzip ovpn.zip
```

Visit this address and get a local recommended server to you:
https://nordvpn.com/servers/tools/

Open Ubuntu `Settings -> Network` and click `+` by VPN and choose `Import from file...`

Choose the relevant downloaded .ovpn file from `~/Downloads`

Enter your nordvpn username/passsword

Now you can enable/disable VPN from Ubuntu network settings or the Ubuntu top-right dropdown menu without re-entering password.

Optional if you always want to run via VPN then run `nm-connection-editor` and edit the settings of your NETWORK CONNECTION (not your VPN)
(General Tab) to auto-connect to your chosen VPN.

Comment: When I run wget I get ```--2021-01-23 15:28:18--  https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/archives/servers/ovpn.zip
Resolving downloads.nordcdn.com (downloads.nordcdn.com)... 104.17.167.30, 104.17.168.30, 2606:4700::6811:a81e, ...
Connecting to downloads.nordcdn.com (downloads.nordcdn.com)|104.17.167.30|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Comment: Not sure, try putting the URL in a browser? For me it works both ways. Maybe the link is blocked in your country?

Comment: it does not work in my browser