# NordVPN Constantly Connects then Disconnects after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, upgrade

Upgraded from 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 focal a couple of months ago. Everything works great except when running Nordvpn my internet connection connects and disconnects every 3 or 4 minutes continuously. When i disconnect from Nordvpn the issue stops.
Ive had ~20 responses from Nordvpn support in attempt to fix the issue to no avail.
Nordvpn works with no issues on my Windows10 PC and another PC running Mint 19.3 it also was working fine on this PC when running 18.04 prior to my upgrade.
Any help is appreciated.
Let me know what additional information is needed.
(Please keep in ming I am a novice linux user!
Thanks.

Comment: some things you might try

nordvpn set autoconnect on us2435   (or just us or what you prefer)

nordvpn countries

nordvpn cities 

https://nordvpn.com/servers/

nordvpn set killswitch on     ( though I dont think this works to kill internet if vpn goes down) or better still set it off if there in 'nordvpn settings' as in 'nordvpn set killswitch off, that could expose you though

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the NordVPN client software? I had nothing but trouble from that but then found out you don't need the client software at all, so I uninstalled, set up VPN within the Ubuntu network settings and never had any problems since.

See my post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310369/error-when-running-apt-get-update-for-nordvpn/1310376#1310376) for instructions:

Comment: I was using the terminal login using nordvpn connect (not sure if that is the client software).

Comment: I was using the terminal login using nordvpn connect (not sure if that is the client software). i did not uninstall nordvpn but i did disconnect from it in terminal. I then setup ubuntu network settings method described in your link and it is working so far and no disconnects so far! Question  - It seems the recommended server for my location changes each time i check on Norvpn so if the recommended server becomes slow i will need to repeat the steps each time or can/should i create several and choose another if one

Comment: I have had zero disconnects from VPN since applying your method. Thanks for your help eliminating such an annoyance!!!