# Ubuntu 20.04 nordvpn installation problem

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I try to install nordvpn on ubuntu 20.04 but it keeps showing me something like this

```
luzw@PL005029:~$ sudo apt install nordvpn
[sudo] password for luzw: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed
  nordvpn
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 71 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13,8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 42,6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up dash (0.5.10.2-6) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package dash (--configure):
 installed dash package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dash
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
luzw@PL005029:~$
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: The problem is, as always, *6 not fully installed or removed*. Whenever you have broken packages you can't install anything else with apt. You need to correct that first. This has nothing to do with the specific package - nordvpn - you're trying to install.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` and then  `sudo apt upgrade`. These two commands will update your system.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, and how can i fix it?

Comment: @user68186 still not working and sudo apt upgrade has the same problem as installing nordvpn

Comment: You could try using NordVPN without the client. I found the client to be buggy and had nothing but problems. Without the client all is well. And quite easy to use once setup. Details here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310369/error-when-running-apt-get-update-for-nordvpn/1310376#1310376